Sum column A based on condition with color on other column
Let's have table like this:

I would like to put the SUM of D5-D7 in cell H10 IF their corresponding cell in column H is colored. I would do the same for all the rest of the dates.
The result shall be like this:

I know I can use SUMIF for counting D column but I am not able to create conditions that would take into account other cells

You can't do this with just formulas.

Please share the Conditional Formatting formula you are using in cell H5 or at least whether columns E:G have formulas or values. This is the information you need to use, not colors.

I'd suggest you to use something else than color to highlight which cells you want to sum up. Colors are not a safe/suitable way to handle information on the machine side. They can be good only for the user. Perhaps enter a value into those cells? You can use a conditional formatting to make them looks just colored while using their value to acutally discriminate what to sum up.

You can even adapt this example to your need and create a little tool to help you easily fill the cells you want with specific colors and values.

Why are you using american date format in columns F and G but european date format in row 3? Anyway, those values in row 3 are stored as date? Do they have years?

I guess you have probably stored them as date but the year is 2024, not 2025. After all 1/1/24 is monday (pondelok). You might wanna check that.

@VBasic2008 there is no Conditional Formatting done so far... user is setting it up based on the dates from F and G collumn...

Assuming that the dates in row 3 are real dates formatted as d/m, in H10 you could use =SUMPRODUCT($D5:$D9*($F5:$F9<=H$3)*($G5:$G9>=H$3)) and copy to the right. This, of course, has nothing to do with the colors (and it shouldn't).

I guess the point was not to base the sum on colors but on those dates. Assuming those values in row 3 are dates (therefore 1/1 stands for Jan 1 2025, 2/2 for Jan 2 2025 and so on), use this formula:
=SUMIFS($D$5:$D$7,$F$5:$F$7,"<="&H3,$G$5:$G$7,">="&H3)

This did the job perfectly. Despite not being based on colors, it does not require recent versions, other macros, or anything else. Thanks :)

As BigBen commented, this cannot be done with formula alone.
I would suggest considering the suggestions in the comments first.

Here's a way to do it using GET.CELL https://xlladdins.github.io/Excel4Macros/get.cell.html

caveat: the file needs to be saved as macro enabled instead of regular workbook
this requires Excel for Microsoft 365 (for LAMBDA and MAP)
add a named function cellColor in Name Manager
=LAMBDA(cells, MAP(cells, LAMBDA(cell, GET.CELL(38,cell))))

38: Shade foreground color as a number in the range 1 to 56. If color is automatic, returns 0.


when multiplying, TRUE from (cellColor(H5:U7) > 0) will be converted to 1
We then get get column-wise sum with MMULT

=MMULT(SEQUENCE(, ROWS(D5:D7), 1, 0), (cellColor(H5:U7) > 0) * D5:D7)



Will try this but I am not sure if that will be possible. My version of Excel is pretty old and I don't see GET.CELL anywhere... I suppose Excel 2013 is way to old for that :D. I will ask end user for the version and based on that I will try it ... thanks :)

@Karcel, GET.CELL is available only in Name Manager, to my knowledge in older versions also; it is not visible/available in formula bar. But SEQUENCE and LAMBDA are available in newer versions only.
